# Why do you use " in front of a number?

Tags: mysql

So I came across the expression "1"="1 and was wondering as to why you write for the first 1 both quotation marks and for the second 1 only the first?
Also is the first 1 registered as a number or rather as a character?

Comment: First one should be treated as a string-based data type (e.g. char), no clue what the second one is. Can you provide more context on the full statement you saw?

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. Btw it was an example for a sqli, and I think I know where the first " comes from. My guess is that there is a LIKE query which probably ends with a ", so the statement would look like: LIKE "" OR "1"="1 ";

Comment: What's a "sqli"?  Please copy the query exactly so we can see some more context.

Comment: @RickJames SQL Injection. You shouldn’t be using this, you should be protecting yourself against SQL injection by using parameterized queries and not trusting any user input.